# Shortening "who/which is" to an -ing form

Tags: grammar

*The boy **being small** is the fastest.* = *The boy **who is small** is the fastest.*

Another example:

*The city **being very beautiful** is worth visiting.*

instead of:

*The the city **which is very beautiful** is worth visiting.*

I couldn't find any sources explaining this (or, I couldn't find any sources ***which explain*** this?) or telling me why this is possible.

Can you tell if and when this is possible and, if so, what makes it correct?

I am not so sure about the first two examples being correct but I am fairly sure the third one ("I couldn't find any sources explaining this") is. Is this perhaps a gerund?

Answer (score 2):

Taken in a single breath group, "The boy being small" would normally be parsed as meaning "The fact that the boy is small", so it does not make sense in this case. (Some people insist on "The boy's being small" for this use).

So it would have to be read as though the participal phrase was a separate breath group: "The boy, being small, is the fastest" - careful writers would write the commas, to reflect the pause in speech before and after "being small".

However, as mattdm says, this means  "The boy, who is small, is the fastest", which is not the same as "The boy who is small is the fastest". 
The first, with the relative clause in a separate breath group (represented by the commas) has a *non-restrictive* or commenting relative clause - it is making an incidental observation about the boy, who must be identified in some other way. Without the pause "The boy who is small is the fastest" has a *restrictive* or defining, or identifying relative clause: it is identifying the boy by his smallness.

In summary: a relative clause can be restrictive or non-restrictive, the latter as a separate breath group. A participial phrase like "being small" may replace a non-restrictive relative clause, but not a restrictive one.

Comment: So had I added the commas I could have used being small?

Comment: Only if you intend it to be non-restrictive.

Comment: So again non restrictive implies that I dont deem "who is small" essential information? Whereas "The boy who is small is the fastest" puts emphasis on his being small to the point where the sentence would not work without this information being added? If I understood correctly.

Comment: Sort of. The way I prefer to think about it is that a restrictive clause narrows down (specifies) the person being talked about, whereas a non-restrictive one doesn't, but just comments on them.

Comment: @Colin Fine could you please see my comment under mattdm's post? I really appreciate your opinion on this :)

Comment: I actually read "the boy, being small, is the fastest" as meaning that the boys smallness is the reason for his speed, it's not just a comment on his size. "The boy, who is small, [...]" is just a comment on his size, though.

Comment: You're right, @AlanThird, that is also a possible reading which hadn't occurred to me. It still requires the participial phrase as a separate breath group, though.

Comment: Can you also tell me which role "explaining" assumes in: "I couldn't find any sources explaining this."

Comment: And the "coming up" in : "Are you going to any events coming up?" Answer would be very helpful.

Comment: @L.White: I would say that in both cases this is a participial phrase that is synonymous with a restrictive relative clause "which explain this" and "which are coming up".

Answer (score 1):

This construct sounds awkward without commas; I would put your examples like this:

> The boy, being small, is the fastest.
>
> The city, being very beautiful, is worth visiting.

In both cases, the clauses mean something different from "who is" or "which is". They implies that this is the *reason* for your conclusion. The boy is fastest *because* he is small. The city is worth visiting *because* it is beautiful.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. What about the third example though? I dont think I can make this work with because as since or any of those.  ( I couldnt find any sources explaining this.) If this one is correct I dont think there is a difference in meaning as opposed to the two you have given explanations to.

Comment: +1. Is there a term for the "being small" clause?

Comment: I guess adjective phrase is what I was looking for here.

Comment: I don't think assuming that _**the city which is beautiful**_ and _**the city being beatiful** are the same structure_ is a good idea because _**present participle phrase**_ _(here being beautiful) is used to give a reason why the city is worth visiting. While in _the city which is beautiful_ the _**adjective clause**_ starting with _which_ modifies the city! In other words, the following is the implied meaning in each sentence:

Comment: > Because/since the city is beautiful, it's worth visiting = being beautiful, the city is worth visiting.

> That beautiful city (not other cities) is worth visiting = the city which is beautiful is worth visiting.

Comment: _The city being beautiful_ is not (or barely) parsable as a noun phrase modified by a participial phrase: it is only parsable as a noun phrase of which the head is "being". You can argue about what it might mean if it were parsable that way, but it isn't, so your argument is pointless.